# IdentityServer v3 to v4 Database Migration

Tags: identityserver4, identityserver3

I am currently migrating data from IdentityServer v3 Database Schema to IdentityServer v4 Database Schema.  Can you confirm that I have the following table mappings correct:

- ClientRoles (v3) -> ClientClaims (v4)
- ScopeClaims -> ApiScopeClaims
- ScopeRoles -> ApiScopeClaims
- Scopes -> ApiScopes
- ScopeSecrets -> ApiSecrets

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Jude

Answer (score 0):

In 4 they split out scopes into resources and scopes (resources being collections of scopes) and further split by API and Identity resources so you need to take this into account too. The simplest way to model it is a 1-to-1 relationship between a resource and a scope.